# How to remove html code from json response

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to call get_child method through ajax in my form textbox change event. I want to show results in datalist. below is the code i have used.

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_child Where `id_mother`=?";
    $results = $db->load_result($sql,array('M-00000001'));
    $child = array();
    foreach($results as $row){  
        $child[]=$row;
    }
    echo json_encode($child,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    die;
```

my script is:

```
$('#mother_name').on('keyup', function(e){
     //e.preventDefault();       
    $.ajax({
        url:"<?php echo $this->to_url('get-child'); ?>",
        type:"GET",
        datatype : "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function(data, status){
            console.log(data);
            //$(data).each(function() {
            //  names = "<option value=\"" + this.id_child + "\">" + this.child_name + "</option>";
            //  $('#childname').append(names);
            //});

        },
        error: function(xhr, desc, err){
            console.log(xhr);
        }
    });
});
```

but when i calling, following output is displayed. it contain html tags with results. when i select particular data from the result it said 'undefined' how can i solve this problem pls help me. i'm new to json.

- Menu
- Menu2

```
[
{
    "id_child": "0000000001",
    "id_mother": "M-00000001",
    "child_name": "marli",
    "child_lname": "",
    "dob": "2015-05-09 00:00:00",
    "gender": "1",
    "birth_weight": "3100.00",
    "birth_height": "55.00",
    "head_Perimeter": "34.00",
    "reg_by": "O-00000001",
    "created_date": "2016-05-12 21:40:25",
    "10": "2016-05-12 21:40:25"
}]
```

[this is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffqjn.png)

thank you guys

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are asking.

Comment: Show an example of a json with html tags

Comment: how can get specific value from the json response. problem is  my jquery return my header information with array result and response type is String.

Answer (score 0):

```
[
{
    "id_child": "0000000001",
    "id_mother": "M-00000001",
    "child_name": "marli",
    "2": "Kathirvelan",
    "child_lname": "",
    "dob": "2015-05-09 00:00:00",
    "gender": "1",
    "birth_weight": "3100.00",
    "birth_height": "55.00",
    "head_Perimeter": "34.00",
    "reg_by": "O-00000001",
    "created_date": "2016-05-12 21:40:25",
    "10": "2016-05-12 21:40:25"
}]
```

From my understanding there are no html in here rather it is a array of elements .

Comment: see my output image

Answer (score 0):

```
 data =   [
    {
        "id_child": "0000000001",
        "id_mother": "M-00000001",
        "child_name": "marli",
        "child_lname": "",
        "dob": "2015-05-09 00:00:00",
        "gender": "1",
        "birth_weight": "3100.00",
        "birth_height": "55.00",
        "head_Perimeter": "34.00",
        "reg_by": "O-00000001",
        "created_date": "2016-05-12 21:40:25",
        "10": "2016-05-12 21:40:25"
    }]

Where is the html tag in the above output? and if you want to read any object value

console.log(data[0].id_child);

because its an array object, you have to put index to read the value.
```

Comment: thanx @sikander. but error indicates in console, that header is undefined

Comment: $.ajax({
        url:"<?php echo $this->to_url('get-child'); ?>",
        type:"GET",
        datatype : "json",
        headers:"contentType:application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function(data, status){
            console.log(data);
           

        },
        error: function(xhr, desc, err){
            console.log(xhr);
        }
    }); 
use this ajax method(define headers)